# Combining Javascript,Jquery with PHP,Mysql for a tooltip

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, css

I have a question. I got stuffed up with this template that uses custom made tooltips. Now is there a tooltip used with an userprofile inside. Pretty nice and all, but also 100% useless because it gets called with class="user-tooltip". That is not really handy when there are more than 1 users, that are using the website.

So I got this idea, to replace the 'user' in class="user-tooltip" with the username collected from the database. (That is $rowuser[0])

But I can not get it working. Even the .css files with the _strike-user are copied and placed in the while() loop of the mysql. Where the user is replaced with $rowuser[0].

Is there a way to automatically show all the user tooltips with this Jquery script? Or is this a nice artistic look for the site, but completely unusable?

Thank you for the effort reading my problem!

PS, when using this with include(), it seems that the jquery script includes the 's and things in the , created by the jquery. Inputs the whole script and then the whole site is lower. So there are then 2  and .. Very weird.

**user-tooltips.php**

```
    jQuery("body").append("<div id='_strike-user'></div>");

    // content tooltip

    jQuery('#_strike-user').hover(function() {
        isinsitememb = true;
    },function() {
        if(timerb) {
            clearTimeout(timerb);
            timerb = null;
        }
        isinsitememb = false;
        timerb = setTimeout(function() {
            if(isinsitememb == true)return false;
            jQuery("#_strike-user").removeClass("active");
            jQuery("#_strike-user").html("");
        }, 500);
    });

    jQuery('.user-tooltip').hover(function() {
        if(timerb) {
            clearTimeout(timerb);
            timerb = null;
        }
        var offset = jQuery(this).offset();
        var position = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
        var karsejmeitene = offset.top-position;
        if(karsejmeitene <= 200){
            jQuery("#_strike-user").addClass("upsidedown");
        }else{
            jQuery("#_strike-user").removeClass("upsidedown");
        }
        jQuery("#_strike-user").html('<a href="#" class="username" style="background:#232323;color:#fff;">John Doe</a><a href="#" class="avatar online"><span class="wrapimg" style="display:inline-block;position:relative;border-radius:inherit;-moz-border-radius:inherit;overflow:hidden;"><img src="images/photos/avatar-11.jpg" alt="" /></span></a><div class="info"><div>"The one who digs a hole, has a shovel"</div><div><font>Group:</font><span class="admin-ribbon">main admin</span></div><div><font>Now:</font>Reading topic "<a href="#"><b>Do you wanna be a billionaire ?</b></a>"</div></div><div class="clear-float"></div><div class="bottom"><a href="#" class="com-control"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>Private message</a><a href="#" class="com-control"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i>View profile</a></div>');
        jQuery("#_strike-user").css("left", offset.left+"px").css("top", offset.top+"px");
        var wii = (parseInt(jQuery(this).css("width"))/2);
        var wiiii = ((parseInt(jQuery("#_strike-user").css("width"))+parseInt(jQuery("#_strike-user").css("padding-right"))+parseInt(jQuery("#_strike-user").css("padding-left")))/2);
        timerb = setTimeout(function() {
            jQuery("#_strike-user").css("margin-left", ((wiiii-wii)*(-1))+"px");
            jQuery("#_strike-user").addClass("active");
        }, 500);
    },function() {
        if(timerb) {
            clearTimeout(timerb);
            timerb = null;
        }
        timerb = setTimeout(function() {
            if(isinsitememb == true)return false;
            jQuery("#_strike-user").removeClass("active");
            jQuery("#_strike-user").html("");
        }, 500);
    });
```

Comment: Are you writing javascript in php files? If so, that is your first problem right there. Javascripts go in .js (most of the time).

Comment: Yeah the problem with that is that I need to use a while() loop before the actual javascript. And within a .js file, I can not get it to work.

Comment: A jsfiddle as an example would help us..

Comment: I created a jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/1y5nfe6j/) But I can not re-create the things that done by the template. (see http://tinyurl.com/nhalmwk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I fixed it!**

I changed this

`jQuery("#_strike-user").html('Here was the LONG LONG Html code of the tooltip');`

To this:

```
var whatauser = jQuery(this).attr("data-title");
jQuery("#_strike-user").load( "ajax/profile_fetch.php?user="+whatauser );`
```

And using the following HTML code to load the tooltip:

```
class="avatar online user-tooltip" data-title="--username with php--"
```

In the profile_fetch.php I am using all the html code of the tooltip + the php generated results that are returned by the MYSQL database.

```
        echo'<a href="/profile/user1/" class="username" style="background:#232323;color:#fff;">User1</a>';
    echo'<a href="/profile/user1/" class="avatar '.$comuser.'">
            <span class="wrapimg" style="display:inline-block;position:relative;border-radius:inherit;-moz-border-radius:inherit;overflow:hidden;">
                <img src="avatar.png" alt="user1" style="width:90px; height:90px;" />
            </span>
        </a>';


    echo'<div class="info">
            <div>
                "The one who digs a hole, has a shovel"
            </div>

            <div>
                <font>Group:</font>
                <span class="admin-ribbon">main admin</span>
            </div>

            <div>
                <font>Now:</font> Reading topic 
                    "<a href="#"><b>Do you wanna be a billionaire ?</b></a>"
            </div>
        </div>';


    echo'<div class="clear-float"></div>';

    echo'<div class="bottom">
            <a href="#" class="com-control">
                <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>Private message
            </a>

            <a href="#" class="com-control">
                <i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i>View profile
            </a>
        </div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

**usertooltip.php**

```
        <?php header("Content-type: application/javascript"); session_start(); include('../../db.connect.php');
        $js_time = strtotime('-30 minutes', time());
        $sqlonline = mysql_query("SELECT twitchid FROM users_hash WHERE timestamp >= '".strtotime('-30 min')."'") or die(mysql_error());

            if(mysql_num_rows($sqlonline) > '0'){
                while($rowonline = mysql_fetch_row($sqlonline)){

                $sqlonuser = mysql_query("SELECT id,avatar,username FROM users WHERE twitchid = '".$rowonline[0]."'") or die(mysql_error());
                $rowonuser = mysql_fetch_row($sqlonuser); ?>    

        (function ($) {     

        jQuery("body").append("<div id='_strike-<?php echo $rowonuser[2]; ?>'></div>");

        jQuery('#_strike-<?php echo $rowonuser[2]; ?>').hover(function() {
            isinsitememb = true;
        },function() {
            if(timerb) {
                clearTimeout(timerb);
                timerb = null;
            }
            isinsitememb = false;
            timerb = setTimeout(function() {
                if(isinsitememb == true)return false;
                jQuery("#_strike-<?php echo $rowonuser[2]; ?>").removeClass("active");
                jQuery("#_strike-<?php echo $rowonuser[2]; ?>").html("");
            }, 500);
        });

        jQuery('.<?php echo $rowonuser[2]; ?>-tooltip').hover(function() {
            if(timerb) {
                clearTimeout(timerb);
                timerb = null;
            }
            var offset = jQuery(this).offset();
            var position = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
            var karsejmeitene = offset.top-position;
            if(karsejmeitene <= 200){
                jQuery("#_strike-<?php echo $rowonuser[2]; ?>").addClass("upsidedown");
            }else{
                jQuery("#_strike-<?php echo $rowonuser[2]; ?>").removeClass("upsidedown");
            }
            jQuery("#_strike-<?php echo $rowonuser[2]; ?>").html('<a href="#" class="username" style="background:#232323;color:#fff;"><?php echo $rowonuser[2]; ?></a><a href="#" class="avatar online"><span class="wrapimg" style="display:inline-block;position:relative;border-radius:inherit;-moz-border-radius:inherit;overflow:hidden;"><img src="images/photos/avatar-11.jpg" alt="" /></span></a><div class="info"><div>"The one who digs a hole, has a shovel"</div><div><font>Group:</font><span class="admin-ribbon">main admin</span></div><div><font>Now:</font>Reading topic "<a href="#"><b>Do you wanna be a billionaire ?</b></a>"</div></div><div class="clear-float"></div><div class="bottom"><a href="#" class="com-control"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>Private message</a><a href="#" class="com-control"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i>View profile</a></div>');
            jQuery("#_strike-<?php echo $rowonuser[2]; ?>").css("left", offset.left+"px").css("top", offset.top+"px");
            var wii = (parseInt(jQuery(this).css("width"))/2);
            var wiiii = ((parseInt(jQuery("#_strike-<?php echo $rowonuser[2]; ?>").css("width"))+parseInt(jQuery("#_strike-<?php echo $rowonuser[2]; ?>").css("padding-right"))+parseInt(jQuery("#_strike-<?php echo $rowonuser[2]; ?>").css("padding-left")))/2);
            timerb = setTimeout(function() {
                jQuery("#_strike-<?php echo $rowonuser[2]; ?>").css("margin-left", ((wiiii-wii)*(-1))+"px");
                jQuery("#_strike-<?php echo $rowonuser[2]; ?>").addClass("active");
            }, 500);
        },function() {
            if(timerb) {
                clearTimeout(timerb);
                timerb = null;
            }
            timerb = setTimeout(function() {
                if(isinsitememb == true)return false;
                jQuery("#_strike-<?php echo $rowonuser[2]; ?>").removeClass("active");
                jQuery("#_strike-<?php echo $rowonuser[2]; ?>").html("");
            }, 500);
        }); 
    });

<?php       }
        }
?>
```

Will output the following in the sourcecoding:

```
        <script async="" src="//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script><script async="" type="text/javascript" src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pub-config/ca-pub-5906080503283942.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">
        // content tooltip
        (function ($) {     

                jQuery("#_strike-refferic").html('<a href="#" class="username" style="background:#232323;color:#fff;">refferic</a><a href="#" class="avatar online"><span class="wrapimg" style="display:inline-block;position:relative;border-radius:inherit;-moz-border-radius:inherit;overflow:hidden;"><img src="images/photos/avatar-11.jpg" alt="" /></span></a><div class="info"><div>"The one who digs a hole, has a shovel"</div><div><font>Group:</font><span class="admin-ribbon">main admin</span></div><div><font>Now:</font>Reading topic "<a href="#"><b>Do you wanna be a billionaire ?</b></a>"</div></div><div class="clear-float"></div><div class="bottom"><a href="#" class="com-control"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>Private message</a><a href="#" class="com-control"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i>View profile</a></div>');

        });

    </script>

    </head><body class="has-top-menu has-dat-menu"><div id="dat-menu" class="effect-1"><div class="dat-menu-container" style="background: url(http://whatameowful.co.uk/images/bg.jpg) 50% 0% / auto repeat scroll padding-box border-box rgb(23, 23, 23);"><div class="dat-menu-top-header"><a href="#dat-menu" class="dat-menu-menu"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a><a href="#" class="dat-menu-search"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a><a href="#"><img src="images/logo.png" style="background-color: #0589cd;" alt=""></a><form action=""><input type="text" name="s" value=""><input type="submit" value=""></form></div><div class="dat-menu-wrapper dat-menu-padding"><div id="_strike-refferic"></div>



     <!-- THE REAL <HEAD> -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
```